# SQL Select all rows from FIRST_TABLE that are not displayed on SECOND_TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I was learning SQL, but can't figure out how to write one query, my tables goes like this:

FIRST_TABLE

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║  USER        ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║
║  5 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║
║  6 ║ Rogger Masas ║
║  7 ║ Josh   Dixon ║
║  8 ║ Tom  Spolsky ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

SECOND_TABLE

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  USER        ║ GROUP║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 5636 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  148 ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║  101 ║
║  6 ║ Rogger Masas ║  148 ║
║  7 ║ Josh   Dixon ║  101 ║
║  8 ║ Tom  Spolsky ║  959 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

And I need a query to select all from FIRST_TABLE, but remove all rows that contains same ID in SECOND_TABLE

Result should look like this

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║  USER        ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║
║  5 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` is usually a good method:

```
select t1.*
from first_table t1
where not exists (select 1 from second_table t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```